# Подсчитаь количество удалений каждого символа

Tags: c#

Программа удаляет заданные символы строки 1, которые есть в строке 2. Подсчитывает новый размер и общее количество удалений. Помогите сделать подсчет удалений каждого конкретного символа

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string t1, t2;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 lines "); ;
    t1 = Console.ReadLine();
    t2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int count = t1.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < t2.Length; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int id = t1.IndexOf(t2[i]);
            if (id == -1)
                break;
            t1 = t1.Remove(id, 1);
        }
    }
    Console.Write($"\n{t1}\n\nRemoved = {count - t1.Length}\n\nNew size = {t1.Length}\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Эта, за Вас написать?

Comment: @Igor намекните хоть

Comment: Намекаю: заведите массив целых с длиной `t2.Length`, инициализированный нулями. На каждое `t1.Remove` увеличивайте число в соответствующей позиции массива.

Comment: @Igor благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3аведите массив целых с длиной `t2.Length`, инициализированный нулями. На каждое `t1.Remove` увеличивайте число в соответствующей позиции массива.